# If we have 12 partitioning keys and we have only 8 Reducers, how many op files will be generated?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

**If we have 12 partitioning keys and we have only 8 Reducers, how many op part files will be created ?**

Will the no of part files created be 12 even though 4 reducers will work for 2 keys. ie. Will 1 reducer emit 2 part files since it is taking 2 keys (for 4 Reducers) OR the data of two keys (given to 1 Reducer) will be merged into one part file hence generating only 8 part files ?

Comment: How do you have more partitions than reducers?

Answer (score 1):

The number of part files created will be 8 if  4 reducers works for 2 keys.A reduce task will produce only one part file even is it takes multiple keys.A reduce task partition may contain multiple keys and they are sorted.Reduce method in Reducer class will get this keys in the sorted order of the key.

You can read more about this from the following links.

1)[Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#partitioning)

2)[hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/shuffle-and-sort)

Comment: But the this would be contradictory to what partition.class code will mean.  The partitioning keys are 12 in number so user would expect 12 output part files. Since the no of Reducers are less... will the job abend or will one reducer emit multiple part files--- is the question.

Comment: The default partitioner in Hadoop is the HashPartitioner which has a method called getPartition. It takes `key.hashCode() & Interger.MAX_VALUE` and finds the modulus using the number of reduce tasks.

For example, if there are 10 reduce tasks(set using `job.setNumReduceTsk()`), getPartition will return values 0 through 9 for all keys.This value will determine which all keys should go to a specific reduce task.This method can return same value for more than one key,in that case those keys with same return value from getPartition  will be grouped under same reduce task.

Comment: Please try to understand my question. I understand the default partitioning case. I want to know what will happen when we write custom partition class and we mention 12 keys in it and we set job.setNumReduceTsk to 8. In this case what will happen?

Comment: In your case,according to my understanding there will be exactly 8 reduce tasks will run and 8 output files will be created.

Comment: can you please provide some explanation supporting the answer. If this is the case then there is no meaning to our custom partition code. The keys for which we want partitioned data are mixed for 4 reducers. Hence the significance of the partition class will be lost.